# How to disappear trails of first dialog when I open new sweet alert dialog?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a delete button when user click it I want a sweet alert which asks for confirmation and once the user click yes and confirm then I want to disappear current confirmation alert and show another alert which tells user deleted and then after 2 seconds page reloads.
i have done it but my issue is when user click on confirmation alert he get the another alert but with some trails of previous alert. ([this is the snip showing trails in red boxe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sUHKI08o0kXBivZeRpdSwgjWg7jzaFf6/view?usp=sharing)) (I did not uploaded them here because I can not due to reputation).

my js is

```
function deleteUser(userRow) {
var objUserRow = jQuery.parseJSON(unescape(userRow));


swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this user again",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: false,
}, function (isConfirm) {


    if (isConfirm) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../users/deleteUser',
            type: 'POST',
            data: objUserRow,
            success: function (data) {

                if (data == "success") {
                    //swal("User Deleted!");

                    swal({
                        title: "Deleted!",
                        text: "User has been deleted successfully!",
                        type: "success",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        closeOnClickOutside: false
                    });
                    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 2000);

                } else if (data == "error") {
                    //this could be due to server side validation or server side error 
                    swal("Error!", "An error has occured at server side", "error");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                swal("Error!", "An error has occured at server side", "error");
            }

        });
    }



});


    }
```

I can not get what I am doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use promises
https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/?_sm_au_=i0HmMJQJFSN6506q#using-promises

```js
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this user again",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: false,
}).then((isConfirm) => {


    if (isConfirm) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../users/deleteUser',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {

                if (data == "success") {
                    //swal("User Deleted!");

                    swal({
                        title: "Deleted!",
                        text: "User has been deleted successfully!",
                        type: "success",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        closeOnClickOutside: false
                    });
                    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 2000);

                } else if (data == "error") {
                    //this could be due to server side validation or server side error 
                    swal("Error!", "An error has occured at server side", "error");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                swal("Error!", "An error has occured at server side", "error");
            }

        });
    }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```